# LIS3MDL runs non-stable

Tags: magnetometer

This chip cannot run the Hall sensors on each power on. The chip can operate with microcontroller each time, the register 'who-am-i' returns `0x3d`, configuration registers are able to read and write. Sometimes the chip returns zeros as magnetic values, only hard reset solves this problem. This happens about 1 time of 10.

This is oscilligraph chart on pin 4 (0.1 uF capacitor) when the Hall sensors works normally:
[image]

[image]

This is oscillograph chart on pin 4 when the Hall sensors doesn't work:

[image]

What should I do?

---

**UPD**

Schematic diagram:

[image: Schematic diagram]

Board fragment:

[image: Board fragment]

> do you mean 1 power-on out of 10

yes

> do you mean only a power-cycle solves this

When I power off the device and then power on, the problem disappears.

> has the design ever worked without this problem in the past?
>
> Do you have multiple sets of this LIS3MDL hardware or only one?

The design ever has the same problem. I have 16 sets. This problem appears on each board.

> What diagnosis have you done so far, with what results?

I detected the difference between working and non-working state as shown on oscilloscope chart. There are no other visible faults.

---

**UPD2**

> the datasheet suggests 1µF paralleled with 0.1µF on the Vdd pin; you have only the latter

The power supply circuit has 10 uF capacitor:

[image: power circuit]

Is it nessesary to add 1 uF capacitor?

Comment: Can you add more background info & explanation e.g. (a) Schematic diagram (b) Close-up photos of the hardware showing the sensor & nearby components (c) Clarify "This happens about 1 time of 10" - do you mean 1 *power-on* out of 10? (d) Clarify "only hard reset solves this problem" - do you mean only a *power-cycle* solves this, or do you mean something else by "hard reset"? (e) What's the project history - has the design ever worked without this problem in the past? (f) Do you have multiple sets of this LIS3MDL hardware or only one? (g) What diagnosis have you done so far, with what results?

Comment: @SamGibson, I've added the information.

Comment: I've operated the same chip, without any issues, but I use I²C mode. Are you sure you're following the datasheet wrt SPI vs I²C mode initialization. I think the CS pin has to be held low on powerup to configure it for SPI.

Comment: Also, the datasheet suggests 1µF paralleled with 0.1µF on the Vdd pin; you have only the latter. I'm using a 4.7µF, no issues here.

Comment: @anrieff, see UPD2.

Comment: Probe the power supply pin on power-on and make sure that the rise time is within the requirements for the IC.

Comment: @anrieff, why CS pin has to be held low? I use MC74VHCT138A to decode CS pin between multiple SPI devices.

Comment: "*Is it nessesary to add 1 uF capacitor?*"
Just to be sure, I'd solder one 1µF on top of the existing 0.1µF. The exact capacitance is not important, but proximity to the chip's supply pins is.

Comment: "*why CS pin has to be held low?*" - I'm not sure, just see if the datasheet says something specifically about required pin states on powerup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for adding the information I requested. Those answers suggest this is a design problem, and not just a faulty component (we didn't know that all of your 16 boards are affected, until those answers).

I agree with the concerns in the answer from *laptop2d* (long ground trace) and the comment from *anrieff* (lack of recommended larger capacitor close to the IC).

Many magnetometers (and, according to [this comment from an ST employee](https://community.st.com/thread/41363-lis3mdl-unexpected-readings#comment-159100), the LIS3MDL device too) take short pulses of high current for the internal magnetic sensors, despite having a low average power consumption. This means that short (i.e. low inductance) traces between the IC and its power decoupling capacitors, are needed.

It's interesting that your test results suggest that the low-current internal logic is operating (at least mostly) correctly as you can read & write the configuration registers; it is the high-current magnetic sensor elements which appear to be malfunctioning. This might again point to problems related to those high-current pulse requirements.

Therefore the long, thin ground trace from the IC is a *big* concern. Also, `C23` seems further away from the IC than it could be.

You mention that you have a 10uF capacitor on the 3.3V rail, but we can't see on the PCB fragment how physically close that capacitor is to the IC. As *anrieff* suggested, you could temporarily piggy-back the recommended 1uF capacitor, on the existing 0.1uF (your `C24`, I think?). However the long, thin ground trace between the IC and `C24` will limit the effectiveness of any decoupling capacitors.

**Suggested test**

On one of your boards, you could try adding the shortest possible, direct wire (e.g. AWG22, not AWG32 "magnet wire") between (a) the IC ground trace *next to the IC* (scrape off the solder resist to get access to the trace) and (b) the closest low-impedance ground node (perhaps directly to the ground pin on `C24`?) - i.e. the wire would go over the top of the IC itself, avoiding the longer trace around `C23`. Then repeat your power-cycle tests.

If that added wire changes the problem behaviour *at all* (even if it doesn't prevent the problem completely) then this confirms the long, thin ground trace is a problem.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will remake the board design according the notes outlined. It will take a few months.

Comment: @maestro - Thanks for the update. If you were able to make the modification I suggested on one of your existing boards, and if that made any change to the symptoms, then that would give some confidence that changing the PCB layout to reduce ground trace inductance will help.

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure the power isn't dropping out at any point. I'm also not liking that long trace to ground, could be the source of common mode noise. Better to put a via on ground next to the chip, otherwise you have a lot of parasitic inductance.
From my estimation of about 20mm of copper this equates to ~20nH of inductance, which could be causing the ground to bounce. If you can, take a differential measurement on that ground trace and make sure there is little or no voltage on it.